# MS Access VBA: Added columns to table but now SQL "INSERT INTO" won't work anymore

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I added two new fields in our table "MTOStudy" & "OtherDesc" as Short Text data types. The other data types within the table are Number and Yes/No values.

However, adding the two columns and updating the table's respective form in Access I can't get to update the table after clicking the button.

Things I've confirmed:

1. The button works, using the message box function.
2. Variables line up with the table's.
3. The code is identical to the working function excluding the addition of the "MTOStudy" and "OtherDesc" variables
4. The Error Code I've been seeing is "Error number: 3078 ; The MS Access db engine cannot find the input table or query '128'. Make sure it exists and that its name is spelled correctly."

Debug's line: **INSERT INTO tbl_MTO_vs_ETO ([Order], [Line], [MTO], [ETO], [DUP], [MTOStudy], [OtherDesc]) VALUES ( , , -1, 0, 0, "TEST ONE PUMP", "")**

Here's the function below:

```
Private Sub btn_save_Click()
'On Error GoTo Err_Execute

    If Me.Check_MTO = False And Me.Check_ETO = False And Me.Check_DUP = False Then
        MsgBox ("Please select one of the classification options."), vbCritical
    Else
    
    Dim Append_SQL As String, tbl_target As String, _
        target_fields As String, field_values As String, _
        errLoop As Error
    
    tbl_target = "tbl_MTO_vs_ETO"

    target_fields = "([Order]," _
    & " [Line]," _
    & " [MTO]," _
    & " [ETO]," _
    & " [DUP]," _
    & " [MTOStudy]," _
    & " [OtherDesc])"
            
    
    field_values = "(" _
    & " " & Me.order & "," _
    & " " & Me.line & "," _
    & " " & Me.Check_MTO.Value & "," _
    & " " & Me.Check_ETO.Value & "," _
    & " " & Me.Check_DUP.Value & "," _
    & " """ & Me.MTOStudy.Value & """," _
    & " """ & Me.OtherDesc.Value & """)"
    
    Call Check_MTO_Dropdown

    Append_SQL = "INSERT INTO " & tbl_target & " " & target_fields & " VALUES " & field_values
    
    CurrentDb.Execute Append_SQL
    
    Debug.Print Append_SQL

    On Error GoTo 0
    
Err_Execute:
    
    If DBEngine.Errors.count > 0 Then
    For Each errLoop In DBEngine.Errors
    MsgBox "Error number: " & errLoop.Number & vbCr & _
    errLoop.description
    Next errLoop
    End If

    'DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.name
    'MsgBox ("Test"), vbOKOnly
    
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Just a wild guess, but have you tried repairing and compacting your database? A corrupt database is often the cause of error messages that don't make sense.

Comment: You must enclose text values within quotes: `& " '" & Me.MTOStudy.Value & "'," _`. But it would be much safer to use [command parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/command-object-parameters).

Comment: You prepare _Append_SQL_ but dont use it the execute command. Is that correct?

Comment: @Heinzi Yes, and I did it again just to make sure. I'm thinking of breaking the "field_values" string into two to isolate the two added variables.

Comment: @Shrotter: I think you nailed it! The numeric value of `dbFailOnError` is 128, that explains the curious error message. :-) Ah, the joys of weak typing and implicit conversions...

Comment: @Shrotter Yes, I did remove it to try the "Dim db as Database" as I originally had "Currentdb.Execute Append_SQL" ; it says that there's a syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

Comment: @Heinzi No, I've already executed the Append_SQL string, received the same error, and forgot to include it for this post. Still getting the same error. Trying Olivier's solution.

Comment: Update your post to show the actual code you are working with NOW - and the current error message - and the results of DEBIG.PRINT Append_SQL. Copy/Paste those results into a Query - SQL View and run it.

Comment: It looks like you have multiple text fields - those need to be enclosed by escaped double quotes. As in '& " """ & Me.OtherDesc.Value & """)"'

Comment: Why do you need SQL to save data input by user? Is this an UNBOUND form? Code doesn't even execute the SQL built and set to Append_SQL variable.

Comment: @dbmitch I've updated the post to reflect my current code. I've always enclosed both text values with double quotes. "Run-time error "3134": Syntax error in Insert Into statement."

Comment: @June7 I need SQL to take the input from within the form and insert that data into the respective table.

Comment: Instead of running RAW SQL I always use a `Recordset` to modify\add records: https://www.accessallinone.com/updating-adding-and-deleting-records-in-a-recordset/

Comment: But if form were bound to table, user input would go directly into table, no code needed. So again, why use VBA and SQL? The line `db.Execute dbFailOnError` is incomplete and meaningless. Don't even show db variable declared and set. Remove line. Use `Debug.Print Append_SQL` and post constructed string in question.

Comment: @June7 My question and code is updated with the "INSERT INTO " statement.

Comment: Still have not addressed all my questions/comments. Do you allow empty string in text fields? - I never do. The SQL is sending an empty string to OtherDesc.

Comment: @June7 I call "Check_MTO_Dropdown" which takes care of that. If MTO is selected and it's not "Other", OtherDesc will default to "N/A". If any other selection is made "ETO/DUP", both MTOStudy and OtherDesc will default to "N/A".

Comment: I would use NZ(<fieldname>,"N/A") for those first two fields or anything that could be null - are Line and Order number or text fields

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As HackSlash mentioned, I too prefer Recordsets.

If you want to go that route, try this:

```
Private Sub btn_save_Click()
    
    'Create new record in tbl_MTO_vs_ETO
        Dim db As DAO.Database
        Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    
        Set db = CurrentDb
        Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tbl_MTO_vs_ETO")
        
            With rs
                .AddNew
                    ![Order] = Order
                    ![Line] = Line
                    ![MTO] = Check_MTO.Value
                    ![ETO] = Check_ETO.Value
                    ![DUP] = Check_DUP.Value
                    ![MTOStudy] = MTOStudy.Value
                    ![OtherDesc] = OtherDesc.Value
                .Update
            End With
    
        rs.Close
        db.Close
    
        Set rs = Nothing
        Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: `db.Close` doesn't actually do anything here.

Comment: @Jeremy Thank you very much! I couldn't for the life of my figure out the DAO nomenclature. I'm reviewing some literature of it now to get a better understanding.

Answer (score 2):

The `VALUES` clause of your `INSERT` statement would trigger Error 3134: *"Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement"* because no values are included before each of the first two commas:

```sql
... VALUES ( , , -1, 0, 0, "TEST ONE PUMP", "")
            ^ ^
```

You need to supply *something* for each of the listed fields.  If those first two fields allow `Null`, you should be able to avoid the error using that:

```sql
... VALUES (Null, Null, -1, 0, 0, "TEST ONE PUMP", "")
```

Comment: @Marcus I attempted to explain why Access complains about "Syntax error".  But I would use a different approach, either a parameter query as Olivier mentioned, or the recordset approach Jeremy gave you.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. I'm new to learning this type of programming, so I don't quite understand it.

Answer (score 1):

If MTOStudy or OtherDesc have quote/apostrophe characters in them (" or ') this will blow up unless you filter these characters out of the input or write yet more code to handle them.  You're much better off using a recordset as HackSlash notes above.

Comment: The SQL is using quote marks to delimit so apostrophes in data should not be an issue. Quote marks in data would.